# Xamarin Forms Dynamically add shell items

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem I have a shell page with a few `ShellContent` links like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
       x:Class="MyApp.SideMenuItems" BackgroundColor="#212121"
       FlyoutBackgroundColor="#212121"
       x:Name="MainShell">

    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <local:SideMenuHeader />
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Image Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="30, 15, 0, 15">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" HeightRequest="35" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    <FlyoutItem Title="SideNav"
                Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" Icon="Home_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Search" Icon="Search_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="Settings_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

Only now I want to add `ShellContent` using C#, but I have no idea how I can do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just like you gave a name `x:Name="MainShell"`, why dont you do the same with the ShellContent items you want to access in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Only now I want to add ShellContent using C#, but I have no idea how I can do that.

If you want to do this in C#, you could try the code below.

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "home",
        };

        shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new ItemsPage() });

        ShellSection shell_section1 = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "about",


        };

        shell_section1.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new AboutPage() });

        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section);
        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section1);
    }
}
```

myshell is the name of Shell.

```
x:Name="myshell"
```

Result:

[image]