# How to set MenuItemTemplate from code behind in Xamarin Forms Flyout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

According to MS documentation, the following is possible for each MenuItem from Xaml. We can customize each MenuItem with different DataTemplates.

```
<MenuItem Text="Help"
              Icon="help.png"
              Command="{Binding HelpCommand}"
              CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell">
        <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
```

How can I do the same from code behind? I'm adding dynamic MenuItems to my flyout but unable to set the DataTemplate.

```
var about = new MenuItem
                {
                    Text = "Privacy policy", 
                    Command = AppShell.AboutCommand
                };

                Shell.Current.Items.Add(about);
```

**Where should I set the Template?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out thanks to Xamarin gitter channel. Special thanks to Shaun Neuville from the Xamarin team!

```
var about = new MenuItem
            {
                Text = "Privacy policy", 
                Command = AppShell.AboutCommand
            };
            Shell.SetMenuItemTemplate(about, (DataTemplate)Shell.Current.Resources["CustomMenuTemplate"]);
            Shell.Current.Items.Add(about);
```

Comment: For maui, `Shell.Current` was `null`. Instead referencing shell by name works. `myshell.Resources["...` and `myshell.Items.Add(...` and on xaml `x:Name="myshell"`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574092/1894630).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `MenuItemTemplate` property of the Shell.

You should be able to set the `DataTemplate` for your Shell MenuItems this way from the Shell class:

```
MenuItemTemplate = GetMenuItemTemplate();
```

Where `GetMenuItemTemplate()` will be either creating the `DataTemplate` from code or loading it from the Resources.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I'm not asking how to set the common DT for MenuItems. I'm asking, how to set one for a specific MenuItem from code behind.

Comment: Did you try with `Shell.Current.MenuItemTemplate` ?

Comment: Shell.Current.MenuItemTemplate is to set the MenuItem template for the whole app. Not for each item.