# Xamarin forms: How to Dynamically (in the app) add menu items from a CRUD function?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crud

*I have a CRUD functionality that works perfectly, what I need to do is to enable adding menu items with the CRUD function.*

*The new item, created with CRUD, shouldbe diplayed here: [Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmLV8.png)*

***I have tried to find solution in the following question: [Xamarin Forms Dynamically add shell items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569567/xamarin-forms-dynamically-add-shell-items), and many others.. But these articles DO NOT answer my question.***

As mentionned I understand your logic but I cannot implement it to my project.. AND I am quite new in this so I'll share some code and hope that someone can help.

**This is my AppShell.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestApplication.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyTestApplication.ViewModels;assembly=MyTestApplication"
        Title="MyTestApplication"
        x:Class="MyTestApplication.AppShell">
        
     <Shell.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                 <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                 <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
             </Style>
             <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
             <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    
             <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                 <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                     <VisualStateGroupList>
                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                             <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                 <VisualState.Setters>
                                     <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                 </VisualState.Setters>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                     </VisualStateGroupList>
                 </Setter>
             </Style>
         </ResourceDictionary>
     </Shell.Resources>
      
    
     <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
             <ShellContent Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
         </FlyoutItem>
         <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="setting.png">
             <ShellContent Route="SettingsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
         </FlyoutItem>
    
     <MenuItem Icon="logout.png" Text="Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnMenuItemClicked">
     </MenuItem>
    
     <TabBar >
         <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
     </TabBar>
    
 </Shell>
```

**This is my AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
public List<ElseMenuItem> FlyoutItems { get; set; } = new List<ElseMenuItem>();

public AppShell()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     private async void OnMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
     }
 }
```

**This is my AddUrl.xaml.cs** (THE ITEMS I WANT TO ADD IN MENU IS "URL BUTTONS" SO WHEN I CLICK, IT TAKES ME TO A SPECIFIC WEBPAGE. THATS WHY I CALL IT ADDURL)

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
     public partial class AddUrl : ContentPage
     {
         private DbService _services;
         bool _isUpdate;
         int urlId;
         public AddUrl()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             _services = new DbService(); // Initializing db service
             _isUpdate = false; // Boolean logic, if constructor calls without any Url parameters it is going to add new record
         }
    
         public AddUrl(Urls obj)
         {
             //If constructor calls parameter of Url object, it is going to update the record
             InitializeComponent();
             _services = new DbService();
             if (obj != null)
             {
                 urlId = obj.Id;
                 TxtUrlName.Text = obj.Name;
                 TxtUrl.Text = obj.Url;
    
    
                 _isUpdate = true;
             }
         }
         private async void btnSaveUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Urls obj = new Urls(); // Use of url object
    
             //Text box value
             obj.Name = TxtUrlName.Text;
             obj.Url = TxtUrl.Text;
    
             // If _isUpdate is true, call UpdateUrls method
             if (_isUpdate)
             {
                 obj.Id = urlId;
                 await _services.UpdateUrls(obj);
             }
             // Else insert record
             else
             {
                 _services.InsertUrls(obj);
             }
             await this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
         }
    
    
     }
```

**This is AddUrl.xaml**

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout Margin="10" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <Entry x:Name="TxtUrlName" Placeholder="Enter Url Name" />
             <Entry x:Name="TxtUrl" Placeholder="Enter Url" />
             <Button x:Name="btnSaveUpdate" Text="Save" Clicked="btnSaveUpdate_Clicked" />
         </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage.Content>
```

**And finally I have a SettingsPage.cs where I have functions to show and add url.**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
     {
      public Settings Settings { get; set; }
         DbService  services;
         public SettingsPage ()
  {
  InitializeComponent();
             // Creates the Settings Model
      Settings = new Settings();
             // Sets the Settings Model as the BindingContext for "filling" the SettingsPage with the current AppSettings.
      BindingContext = Settings;
             services = new DbService();
    
         }
    
         protected async override void OnAppearing()
         {
             showUrl(); // Returns GetAllUrls
             base.OnAppearing();
         }
    
         private void showUrl()
         {
             var res = services.GetAllUrls();
             lstUrls.ItemsSource = res; // Binding with listview
         }
    
    
         //This method is used to insert data into db 
         private async void BtnAddRecord_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddUrl(), true);
    
         }
    
          
    
         // Display alert for update and delete
         private async void lstData_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.SelectedItem != null)
             {
                 Urls obj = (Urls) e.SelectedItem;
                 string res = await DisplayActionSheet("Operation", "Cancel", null, "Update", "Delete");
    
                 switch (res)
                 {
                     case "Update":
                         await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddUrl(obj), true);
                         break;
                     case "Delete":
                         services.DeleteUrl(obj);
                         showUrl();
                         break;
                            
                 }
                  
                 lstUrls.SelectedItem = null;
             }
    
         }
     }
```

AGAIN: I dont know how to implemet the logic in my code.. I have a CRUD function that works perfectly BUT I need to use it to add items in menu dynamically. Hope someone can show me the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your CRUD operation,you could call `Items.Add()` method and `Items.Remove()` method before you operator the database.

like in add the menuitem in **AddUrl.xaml.cs**:

```
private async void btnSaveUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Urls obj = new Urls(); // Use of url object

         //Text box value
         obj.Name = TxtUrlName.Text;
         obj.Url = TxtUrl.Text;

         // If _isUpdate is true, call UpdateUrls method
         if (_isUpdate)
         {
             obj.Id = urlId;
             await _services.UpdateUrls(obj);
         }
         // Else insert record
         else
         {
             _services.InsertUrls(obj);
         }
         AppShell.Current.Items.Add(your menuitem);//add the menuitems
         await this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
     }
```

remove menuitem in **SettingsPage.cs** :

```
private async void lstData_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.SelectedItem != null)
         {
             Urls obj = (Urls) e.SelectedItem;
             string res = await DisplayActionSheet("Operation", "Cancel", null, "Update", "Delete");

             switch (res)
             {
                 case "Update":
                     await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddUrl(obj), true);
                     break;
                 case "Delete":
                     services.DeleteUrl(obj);
                     AppShell.Current.Items.Remove(your menuitem); //remove
                     showUrl();
                     break;
                        
             }
              
             lstUrls.SelectedItem = null;
         }

     }
```

Comment: "AppShell.Current.Items.Remove(your menuitem);", what do you mean by "you menu item"? I cannot find the menu item @Leo Zhu - MSFT

Comment: @Lidprogsky It's your new menuitem which you want to display in the menu.